# Does vba in word and excel uses different declaration?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to use this json converter https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON in microsoft word.

It works excelent in excel with ms-scripting runtime.

however it fails in microsoft word.

the problem I think is object type declaration.

In microsoft word this line gives error.

```
Set json_ParseObject = New Dictionary
```

after reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251782.aspx
I tried converting it to

```
dim json_ParseObject As Dictionary.
```

It give error of duplicative declaration so i removed it.

it then gave error at:

```
Set json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)
```

Does anybody have ever used this project for word-vba successfully?

I earlier asked this question while I was not aware of problem. after some research I am asking it again. Please try to understand the problem as it is real. Please guide if you thing this question is off-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In microsoft word this line gives error.

This is because in `Word` there already exists a class `Dictionary` but this Word class can't be created with `New`. So it is a collision of `Scripting Runtime Dictionary` and `Word Dictionary`.

In Word fully qualify the name of the Dictionaty type with the name of the library:

```
Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

Comment: You are genius man. Where were you last time when asked the same question and was closed because of off topic? Thanks man. I would like to upvote every answer you have given. But I think they monitor vote bomarding. thanks man.